# Почему вызывается метод?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть примерно такой код:

```
const PageClientOne = ({onSubmit, onDelete, client}) => {
    return(
        <form style={styles.enter} onSubmit={_handleSubmit(client,onSubmit)}>
        // ... какой-то код

            <Button type="submit" theme="success">Сохранить</Button>
            <Button type="button"
                            theme="error" onClick={onDelete(client._id)}>Удалить</Button>
        </form>
    )
}

const _handleSubmit = (client, onSubmit) => {
    return event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        onSubmit(client)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        client: state.reducers.clientsState.client
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onSubmit: (client) => {
        dispatch(saveClient(client))
    },
    onDelete: (id) => {
        console.log("DELETE")
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(PageClientOne)
```

Проблема в том что onDelete срабатывает при загрузке страницы, а не только когда кликают по кнопке. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Подумайте, почему с onSubmit не происходит такой же проблемы. У вас в коде уже есть решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Тут тоже необходим event.preventDefault() ? И так всегда? Неужели нет более изящного способа?

Comment: Вы не туда смотрите. preventDefault тут ни при чем.

Comment: Потому что вы его вызываете.

Comment: Что-то вроде `{onDelete.bind(null, client._id)}` теоретически могло бы помочь

Comment: Просто вы сразу вызываете метод, когда пытаетесь подписаться на событие, в вашем случае `onClick={onDelete(client._id)}` заменить на `onClick={() => onDelete(client._id)}`, тоже и с onSubmit. Все заработает как и должно

Comment: Не забывайте, чтобы подписаться на событие, надо передать событию функцию, а вы отдаете РЕЗУЛЬТАТ выполнения функции. Это и решается оберткой вызова метода в стрелочную функцию